# Can somebody explain the difference in output when using if v/s else if for replacing tabs (\t) using C? K&R Exercise 1-10

Tags: c, if-statement, character

I am on windows and using Visual Studio Code.

Question: Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each tab with `\t`, backspace with `\b`, and backslash with `\\`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int c;
    for(c = getchar(); c != EOF ;)
    {
        if(c == '\t')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
        }
        if(c == '\\')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
        }
        if(c == '\b'){
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
        }
        if(c == ' '){
            putchar('\0');
        }      
        else
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
        
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

For the input: `This    is      sparta`

I get the output: `This\t  is\t    sparta`

I thought this was because, tab is 4 spaces and replacing it with `'\t`' meant the remaining 3 spaces get converted to blank space. That's why I added the `if(c == ' '){putchar('\0'); }`  condition.

But, I still get an incorrect output.

If, I instead use `else if`, for the two subsequent conditions for `'\\'` and `'\b'`, I end up with the correct output : `This\tis\tsparta`. Why does this happen?

Comment: *"replacing it with '\t' meant the remaining 3 spaces get converted to blank space"* - whatever gave you that idea, it's wrong. The extra characters are because the last check, `if(c == ' ')` when false (which it is by definition when any of the ones preceding it are true) will falter to the else clause, which replicates whatever `c` was to stdout.

Comment: I know it's wrong, but that was my reason behind adding the 4th condition. But, it still gives an incorrect output. So, I don't really understand what is happening between if vs else if.

Comment: Consider this. You get a tabchar. is the first if-check true ? yes, so dump the backslash and t to stdout. Continuing, is the next if true ? no, `c` is not a backslash; it's still a tabchar. So nothing happens (no else), Moving on, what about the backspace ? Nope, `c` is *still* a tabchar, so nothing there either (and no else). What about the last one (a space) ? Nope, `c` is still a tabchar, so the `if` is false, but *now* there' is an else attached, which you fall into and thus print the tabchar (so you've now printed a backslash, a t, and an actual tabchar. understand ?

Comment: Run through it line by line in a debugger. You'll  see that the `else` case always runs unless the character is a space (which it never is in your example input). When you make the `else if` change then the `else` case does not run when the input is a tab because it would have gone through the first `if`.

Comment: @WhozCraig and kaylum yeah, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical Break-Down

Suppose we read is a tabchar.

```
if(c == '\t') // this is true so...
{
    putchar('\\'); // execute this...
    putchar('t');  // ... and this.
}

if(c == '\\') // this is false. skip the putchars
{
    putchar('\\');
    putchar('\\');
}

if(c == '\b') // this is false. skip the putchars
{
    putchar('\\');
    putchar('b');
}

if(c == ' ') // this is false, skip the putchars and jump to else
{
    putchar('\0');
}      
else // character was not a space, it was a tabchar, so... 
{
    putchar(c); // execute this. writes the tabchar we've had all along
}
```

In short, the posted code will ALWAYS dump whatever character was written *in addition* to whatever prior logic transpired *unless* it was a spacechar (which never is).

Fix this by either

1. chaining your if's to else if's
2. using a switch-case construct
3. invoking `continue;` inside each special processing if-test after the putchars. Make sure to prime `c` with the next character first (or as part of the loop condition if you're creative about it).

Any of the above will work. Which one you choose, I leave to you.